# Issues while adding custom fonts to XCode 6

Tags: ios, fonts, ios8, xcode6, embedded-fonts

I've been using XCode 6 and from what I know, it has the "Live rendering" feature which display custom fonts right on the storyboards.

I want to use Museo Sans, and I have 8 variations (see image). I dragged them into XCode but the weird thing is that it only shows two of them in the style panel (see second image, 100 and Regular).

I've also tried adding them to the "Fonts provided by application" index.

Any guesses why the other ones are not appearing?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

**EDITED:**

I got the same fonts with OTF extension, and they all seemed to work OK. I think it's a TTF bug.

[image]